# How to make core plot y axis marks as .5

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I'm trying to set the y axis marks to .5  but I can't make them any smaller than one.  Here's my code. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
// 4 - Configure y-axis
CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.title = @"";
y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
y.titleOffset = -40.0f;
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
y.labelOffset = 16.0f;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;

NSInteger majorIncrement;
NSInteger minorIncrement;

// set if here to check for inr  5-13
if (self.iNRFlag) {
    majorIncrement = 1;
    minorIncrement = 1;
} else {
    majorIncrement = self.glucoseTick;
    minorIncrement = self.glucoseHalfTick;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code provided doesn't create any tick marks or labels. If you want evenly spaced tick marks, use the default labeling policy (`CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval`) and set the `majorIntervalLength` to `@0.5`. Set the `minorTicksPerInterval` to a value greater than one (1) to insert minor tick marks between the major tick marks. Set the `labelFormatter` to a new `NSFormatter` to control the format of the tick labels.

Comment: HI, Do you have any sample code for this. It's not working for me. When I try this, CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval = .5 it says "expression is not assignable" Thanks for your help

Comment: `y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval; y.majorIntervalLength = @0.5;` There are several example apps included with Core Plot; there are lots of axis labeling examples throughout the *Plot Gallery* app.

Comment: Unfortunately, the following line with xcode 10.2.1 generates the following message.
y.majorIntervalLength = @0.5;

Assigning to 'NSDecimal' from incompatible type 'NSNumber *'

Comment: Use the Core Plot code on the `release-2.3` branch. I don't think release 2.2 will even compile with Xcode 10.

Comment: 2.2 compiles fine

Comment: I am running 2.3 and I have another problem. It is displaying the y-axis below 0 and I only want it to show positive, no y axis below 0

Comment: Set the `yRange` of the plot space to start at zero (0).